# How to iterate over a list of lists in R?

Tags: r, loops, iterator

I am new to `R` and not able to find the counter code in `R` for the following `Python` code.
Please help

```
list1 = [10, 20] # or a tuple
list2 = [30, 40] # or a tuple
mylist = [list1, list2] # can be tuple of tuples also
for _list in mylist:
    a = _list[0]
    b = _list[1]
    # usage of a and b
```

I wrote the following R script:

```
list1 <- list(10, 20)
list2 <- list(30, 40)
mylist <- list(list1, list2)

for( j in 1:length(mylist))
{
    print(j)
    list1=mylist[[j]]
    print(list1)
    # Works perfect till here

    # Error in below lines
    a=list1[[0]]
    b=list1[[1]]
    # usage of a and b
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `R`, indexing starts from 1 and not 0 - difference between `Python` and `R`.  So, if we change it to `1` and `2`, it works.  In addition, `1:length` may be replaced with less buggy `seq_along`

```
for( j in seq_along(mylist)){
    print(j)
    list1 = mylist[[j]]
    print(list1)    
    a=list1[[1]]
    b=list1[[2]]
    # usage of a and b
}
[1] 1
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 20

[1] 2
[[1]]
[1] 30

[[2]]
[1] 40
```

NOTE: `list1`, `a`, `b` are objects created within the loop and this gets updated in each iteration.  It is not clear about the final outcome

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This made a lot of things clear.

Answer (score 1):

A translation of your `python` code might be something like below

```
> for (lst in mylist) {
+   a <- lst[[1]]
+   b <- lst[[2]]
+   print(c(a, b))
+ }
[1] 10 20
[1] 30 40
```